# Database Design Address Book

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to develop a mysql schema for an address book. The uncertainty I have is how to model it because, some contacts will have one phone number and one email address whereas others may have multiples of this. In the frontend I will create a button which allows users to add address fields.

Right now my Model looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    first_names = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_names = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_alt_line = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_zip = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_state = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address_country = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone4 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone5 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email4 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email5 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website3 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website4 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website5 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website6 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website7 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website8 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    website9 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

However I am aware, that this is not very DRY. Another option I have thought of is to create separate models for persons and separate ones for addresses, emails, phone numbers, websites, etc. and then make person.id the foreign key for these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    first_names = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_names = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    alt_line = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class OnlineContact(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is any of these approaches good (enough) or is there a better way to do it? I would prefer not to use a NOSQL db and stick with MySQL. FYI I use Python and Django.

class Person(models.Model):

Comment: 2nd approach (with many models) is exactly how it's meant to be in a relational db (like mysql)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think DRY is related to Design of Model unless you using same model and override it couple time

if split it to 2 models for example : 
users , users_details 
so it logical to separate auth data and personal data 
but in your case it to much separation on Table

why you need so much tables for phone , website , email 
maybe you data design isn't correct

Comment: the separation was only an example, because I don't know how to handle an uncertain amount of fields (e.g. Phone1, Phone2, Phone3, etc.) in one model.

Comment: if you will have unknown number of fields from certain type , so make it different model with ForiegnKey

Comment: if Don't need to make lookup through this data and you Ok with extract it with other Fields you can use JSON data to store multiply items